# Disable desktop Retina/hiDPI scaling for an AIR14 app?

Tags: apache-flex, air, retina-display

I've got a AIR desktop app that I'm upgrading from Flex 3.5 + AIR 2.6 to Flex 3.5 + AIR 14, specifically so that I can disable the Retina/hiDPI pixel scaling that happens automatically. It's making my app look gross on these high density screens.

When a customer explictly disables Retina mode (or hiDPI mode on Win8.1), then my existing app looks great on these screens, and automatically adjusts to make use of the better resolution.

So the only reason I'm upgrading the AIR version is to somehow tell the AIR runtime "Yep! I've designed my app to scale well on high density displays, so please don't lie to me about the available pixels".

I have:

- followed the [official SDK overlay instructions](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html)
- upgraded my app descriptor to the AIR14 namespace.
- Added `<requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>` to the `<initialWindow>` tag in the descriptor
- Added a `-target-player=24` compiler option (since Flex 3.5 doesn't support the `-swf-version=24` option recommended in the official guide. You need to use `-target-player=X` instead)

My app compiles and packages fine, but it still launches in pixel-doubling mode!

What else do I need to do in order to get my desktop AIR app to run at the native resolution of the screen, without any pixel doubling?